# How to grouping data array by same value in other array in laravel php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have some data array like this and i want to regroup this data how to do that and what i suppose to do:

```
[
 {
    "id":18,
    "order_id":9,
    "invoice":"4345787961",
    "product_id":5,
    "seller_id":1,
    "price":5400000,
    "qty":1,
    "weight":10000,
    "cost":25000,
    "shipping":"JNE-25000",
    "tracking_number":null,
    "ref":null,
    "ref_status":0,
    "status":"1",
    "total_per_order":5425000,
    "created_at":"2020-07-06T07:44:23.000000Z",
    "updated_at":"2020-07-06T07:45:31.000000Z",
    "status_order":"<span class=\"badge badge-primary\">Dikonfirmasi <\/span>"
 },
 {
    "id":19,
    "order_id":9,
    "invoice":"2701585840",
    "product_id":4,
    "seller_id":1,
    "price":6199000,
    "qty":1,
    "weight":300,
    "cost":9000,
    "shipping":"JNE-9000",
    "tracking_number":null,
    "ref":null,
    "ref_status":0,
    "status":"1",
    "total_per_order":6208000,
    "created_at":"2020-07-06T07:44:23.000000Z",
    "updated_at":"2020-07-06T07:45:31.000000Z",
    "status_order":"<span class=\"badge badge-primary\">Dikonfirmasi <\/span>"
 },
 {
    "id":20,
    "order_id":9,
    "invoice":"4442318215",
    "product_id":1,
    "seller_id":2,
    "price":9249000,
    "qty":2,
    "weight":2000,
    "cost":96000,
    "shipping":"JNT-96000",
    "tracking_number":null,
    "ref":null,
    "ref_status":0,
    "status":"1",
    "total_per_order":18594000,
    "created_at":"2020-07-06T07:44:23.000000Z",
    "updated_at":"2020-07-06T07:45:31.000000Z",
    "status_order":"<span class=\"badge badge-primary\">Dikonfirmasi <\/span>"
 }
]
```

i want grouping data by seller_id if got same seller_id,if seller_id have same data, data push in save array, something like this:

```
[ 
 [
   {
    "id":18,
    "order_id":9,
    "invoice":"4345787961",
    "product_id":5,
    "seller_id":1,
    "price":5400000,
    "qty":1,
    "weight":10000,
    "cost":25000,
    "shipping":"JNE-25000",
    "tracking_number":null,
    "ref":null,
    "ref_status":0,
    "status":"1",
    "total_per_order":5425000,
    "created_at":"2020-07-06T07:44:23.000000Z",
    "updated_at":"2020-07-06T07:45:31.000000Z",
    "status_order":"<span class=\"badge badge-primary\">Dikonfirmasi <\/span>"
  },
  {
    "id":19,
    "order_id":9,
    "invoice":"2701585840",
    "product_id":4,
    "seller_id":1,
    "price":6199000,
    "qty":1,
    "weight":300,
    "cost":9000,
    "shipping":"JNE-9000",
    "tracking_number":null,
    "ref":null,
    "ref_status":0,
    "status":"1",
    "total_per_order":6208000,
    "created_at":"2020-07-06T07:44:23.000000Z",
    "updated_at":"2020-07-06T07:45:31.000000Z",
    "status_order":"<span class=\"badge badge-primary\">Dikonfirmasi <\/span>"
  }
],
[
  {
    "id":20,
    "order_id":9,
    "invoice":"4442318215",
    "product_id":1,
    "seller_id":2,
    "price":9249000,
    "qty":2,
    "weight":2000,
    "cost":96000,
    "shipping":"JNT-96000",
    "tracking_number":null,
    "ref":null,
    "ref_status":0,
    "status":"1",
    "total_per_order":18594000,
    "created_at":"2020-07-06T07:44:23.000000Z",
    "updated_at":"2020-07-06T07:45:31.000000Z",
    "status_order":"<span class=\"badge badge-primary\">Dikonfirmasi <\/span>"
  }
 ]
]
```

nedd to foreach but i dont know, what i suppose to do..?  Any Ideas everyone can help me

Comment: you can use `map()` or `groupBy()` it depends on your use.

Comment: can you show me the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
collect($array)->groupBy('seller_id');
```

Comment: Ah yes, you read the question correctly. Group by, not key by :) +1 and I'll delete my answer

Answer (score 1):

First you need tot query the product.

```php
$products = Product::all();
```

You can use `groupBy()`

```php
return $products->groupBy('seller_id');
```